# How to iterate over the series: 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, series

How would you iterate over the following series in Javascript/jQuery:

```
1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, ...
```

Here is how I do this:

```
n = 1
while (...) {
  n = ((n % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1) * (Math.abs(n) + 1);
}
```

Is there a simpler method ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could keep two variables:

```
for (var n = 1, s = 1; ...; ++n, s = -s)
  alert(n * s);
```

Comment: It's nice, but is it *simpler*?

Answer (score 4):

This is simpler

```
x = 1;
while (...) {
    use(x);
    x = - x - x / Math.abs(x);
}
```

or

```
x = 1;
while (...) {
    use(x);
    x = - (x + (x > 0)*2 - 1);
}
```

or the much simpler (if you don't need to really "increment" a variable but just to use the value)

```
for (x=1; x<n; x++)
    use((x & 1) ? x : -x);
```

Comment: @Pointy: `x / Math.abs(x)` is `sign(x)` ... what is the part that's not clear?

Comment: @Pointy: nice trick... you comment other solutions as wrong so that yours gets accepted ;-)

Comment: @Misha: it means do whatever you need to do with the value

Answer (score 2):

That looks about right, not much simpler than that.  Though you could use `n < 0` if you are starting with `n = 1` instead of `n % 2 == 0` which is a slower operation generally.

Otherwise, you will need two variables.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var n = 1;
while(...)
    n = n < 0 ? -(n - 1) : -(n + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use the following method:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
  var isOdd = (i % 2 === 1);
  var j = (isOdd - !isOdd) * i;
}
```

Which is similar, by the way, to how you'd get the sign (a tri-state of -1, 0 or 1) of a number in JavaScript:

```
var sign = (num > 0) - (num < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var n = 1; Math.abs(n) < 10; (n ^= -1) > 0 && (n += 2))
   console.log (n);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some **Bit Manipulation** -

```
n = 1;
while(...)
{
    if(n&1)
    cout<<n<<",";
    else
    cout<<~n+1<<",";
}
```

Nothing beats the bits !!

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
while (...) 
{ 
    if (n * -1 > 0) { n -= 1; }
    else { n += 1; } 

    n *= -1;
}
```

seems to be the simplest way.

Comment: this would start with `1`; then `(1+1) * -1 = -2`, then `(-2+1) * -1 = -1`, wouldn't it? you'd get `1, -2, -1`

Comment: I know, I fixed it. Mistakes happen when you don't sleep for 3 days :P

Comment: @MisterSir: Note that `n * -1 > 0` is identical to `n < 0` which is a lot simpler (and what I said in my answer).

Comment: @Orbling True, but if you're going to use this with a compiled language(this question is tagged JS though), it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @MisterSir: Why would it not matter?  Because the compiler would optimise it for you?  That may not be the case.  Such optimisations can occur in interpreted languages as well anyhow.

Comment: @Orbling Modern compilers would optimise that. However, interpreters usually will avoid those kinds of optimisations.

Comment: @MisterSir: Sounds entirely speculation, totally compiler/interpreter dependent.

Comment: @Orbling Just think about it - With almost every case, optimising that would just be unnecessary. Why should an interpreter stall on that, then? On the other hand, compilers generally wouldn't mind stalling on such optimisations.

Comment: @MisterSir: "Stalling on it"? Depends on the engine, Chrome's JS engine does lots of optimisations for instance.  Anyhow, I think we're going massively off topic here.  For what was mainly a comment on code clarity, not performance at all.